# Visual Studio 2015 Can't Deploy Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to deploy a Project from Visual Studio 2015 to a Raspberry Pi 2, running Win 10 IoT.

Got Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, Update 3, etc. all set up.
The sample project "Blinky" does deploy on the Raspberry!

However, when using a different project, there's just no option to deploy. The Deploy Box is greyed out!

Also, there's only the green "Start" button in VS2015, but no way to select a remote machine.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Here's a screenshot, showing how it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the platform drop down to 'ARM' and select your device in the project properties under the Debug options.

[image]